# AngularJS - Can not pass the value from datepicker (undefined)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

So, I am using AngularJS ver 1.x for this project. I also use this library https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker for my datepicker.

Here is my View:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
 <input date-time  ng-model="dates_min" min-date="minDate" view="date" min-view="date" format="yyyy-MM-dd">
 <input ng-model="email" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" style="padding:0px 45px 0px" placeholder="Email">
 <h1>You entered: {{dates_min}}</h1>
 <button ng-click="search(dates_min, email)" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Submit&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
$scope.search = function(dates_min, email) {
 console.log(dates_min + ' ' + email);
}
```

This is the form:
[image: Screen Shot 2017-01-17 at 8.44.48 PM.png]

When I set the date and type any string in the second inputbox then click button submit I got the result 
 **undefined a**
My question is, how to pass the value from datepicker inputbox to my $scope.search function?

Comment: Try without parameters in function get value from datepicker and input with `$scope` like a `$scope.dates_min`

Comment: have you set the $scope. minDate ?

Comment: @htmlbrewery I improved first inputbox with this <input date-time  ng-model="$scope.dates_min" min-date="minDate" view="date" min-view="date" format="yyyy-MM-dd"> and button with this <button ng-click="search()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>.and this is the controller: $scope.search = function() {  console.log($scope.dates_min) } . Still no any luck mate, the result is undefined

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi where I should set the $scope? I try set the $scope in my function in controller but still get undefined

Comment: try by adding $scope.dates_min = {}; on the top of your controller.

Comment: the result still undefined mate :|

Comment: try by adding $scope.dates = {}; on the top of your controller . and in your ng-model put : ng-model="dates.date_min".